# How to re-create box this shadow effect in IE

Tags: css

Here is what I am trying to replicate :

```
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 5px black;
```

This is what I've tried in IE:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color=#000000);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try using `box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 5px black;`

Comment: What IE Version are you trying on?

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color='#00000000');
```

You can test filters here [on MSDN](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/filter/DropShadow.htm)